# MELT: multiple values without duplication

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Cant be this hard. I Have

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],'name':['j','l','m'], 'mnt':['f','p','p'],'nt':['b','w','e'],'cost':[20,30,80],'paid':[12,23,45]})
```

I need

```
 import numpy as np
df1=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,1,2,3],'name':['j','l','m','j','l','m'], 't':['f','p','p','b','w','e'],'paid':[12,23,45,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],'cost':[20,30,80,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})
```

I have 45 columns to invert.

I tried

```
(df.set_index(['id', 'name'])
   .rename_axis(['paid'], axis=1)
   .stack().reset_index())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I think simpliest here is set missing values by `variable` column in [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df2 = df.melt(['id', 'name','cost','paid'], value_name='t')       
df2.loc[df2.pop('variable').eq('nt'), ['cost','paid']] = np.nan

print (df2)
   id name  cost  paid  t
0   1    j  20.0  12.0  f
1   2    l  30.0  23.0  p
2   3    m  80.0  45.0  p
3   1    j   NaN   NaN  b
4   2    l   NaN   NaN  w
5   3    m   NaN   NaN  e
```

Use `lreshape` working with dictionary of lists for specified which columns are `'grouped'` together:

```
df2 = pd.lreshape(df, {'t':['mnt','nt'], 'mon':['cost','paid']})
print (df2)
   id name  t  mon
0   1    j  f   20
1   2    l  p   30
2   3    m  p   80
3   1    j  b   12
4   2    l  w   23
5   3    m  e   45
```

Comment: That fails when I try to use different  multiple columns for one dict and a single column for another dict. Example df2 = pd.lreshape(df, {'t':['r', 'y', 'j', 'k'], 'mon':['P']} ) returns ValueError: All column lists must be same length

Comment: @wwnde - hmm, can you edit question with new expected output?